# Is it possible to create a rectangle drawable with an upwards curve?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shapedrawable

I am trying to create a button background using Android shape drawables. I am trying to have two curves on a rectangle with the one on top being backwards. The background also has a stroke of 3dp which prevents me from using a layer list. This is what I am hoping to create:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="1dp" android:topLeftRadius="-30dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/very_light_grey"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/grey"
        />
</shape>
```

[image: Is this possible with Android shape drawables?]

Is this possible with Android shape drawables?

Comment: LayerList should work for you. The bottom rectangle and the inner rectangle should have same left as the bottom and then you can give curve.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar How would I make the upwards curve though?

Comment: The above image shows the downward curve only but the upward curve should be possible. Though i never made one but i think negative values should do the trick for upward curve.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I tried setting the corner to a negative value but I did not make an upwards curve. What other options do I have to make the shape? Thanks

Comment: please post your drawable xml.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Its posted